# GET httprequest sent values aren't fetched in html page

Tags: javascript, php, function, xmlhttprequest, httprequest

Hi I don't understand why some values taken from JS doesn't fetched correctly via GET method with httprequest.
I read dozens of questions about this argument but I haven't found anything that could help me.

My values are:

```
var giorno = document.getElementById("dataselezionata").value;
var periodo = $('input:radio[name=periodo]:checked').val();
```

The first one is taken from datepicker and the second is a radio button.

In my test the selected values are: giorno = 2017-05-15 and periodo = 2.
The above values could be visible on the page after clicking one of the two radiobuttons.

I want to send these values to the same page "prenotazione" with a function

```
$('input:radio[name=periodo]').change(function() {

    function Invia() {
        var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
        httpRequest.open('GET', "index2.php?a=prenotazione&giorno="+giorno+"&periodo="+periodo);
        httpRequest.send();
        return httpRequest.responseText;
    }
    var result = Invia();
}
```

and the results could be echoed in the same php page with:

```
$giorno     = $_GET['giorno'];
$periodo    = $_GET['periodo'];   

echo"$giorno";
echo"$periodo";
```

and they should provide the values for the Mysql query

```
<?
$qora = DB_Query("SELECT SUM(h1600) as tot FROM $table20n WHERE giorno = '$giorno' AND periodo = '$periodo' ");
$rora = DB_Get_Results($qora);

$totale = $rora[tot];

if($totale >= 2) {
$disabled = invisible;
$bgcolor = FF0000;
} else {
$disabled = '';
$bgcolor = '84D3EB';
}
$conto = ($valore-$totale);

echo"<div style='background-color:#$bgcolor;' >";
echo"16:00</br>";
echo"$conto</br>";
echo"<input class='$disabled' type='radio' value='1' name='orario' id='h1600'>";
echo"</div>";
?>
```

**The problem**

If I check with Firebug Console if the values are sent to the page, I don't receive any error.
The parameters are as described above, the url of the page is

```
http://www.rinnovipatenti.com/index2.php?a=prenotazione&giorno=2017-05-15&periodo=2
```

and finally the firebug html preview show me the requested values.

But if I check on html page nothing appears.
I've just tried many many times using different methods to send the values: ajax post, ajax get, json, json stringify with encode/decode but always without success.
Furthermore there aren't single or double quote on the values that could invalidate it.
I also tried to substitue the variable values with forced values like this:

```
var giorno = '2017-05-15';
var periodo = '2';
```

but the situation doesn't change. I'm going crazy!!

I've been around the problem for two weeks and I'm still at the starting point.
Can someone suggest me how can I do? Any Suggestion is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: So you `get` the content, do you put it anywhere? I could be misunderstanding but it sounds like you want to redirect to the same page with the additional parameters.

Comment: Yes the page collects step by step some values (date, period, hour, name, surname, phone, email) that are submitted at the end with a post form to new page that save the collected data on the database. I want to collect the values without refreshing tha main page